# hover on :before pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I have this navigation menu and I need the circle bullets in front of each line. The **HTML** code is here

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/yY84q/1/

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</a>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS** code:

```
li{list-style-type:none;}
li:before{content:'\00b7'; font-size:100px; line-height:24px; vertical-align:middle;}

li:hover {
    background:gray;
}

li a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

As you can see, when I hover on the bullets themselves, the gray selection is wrong. It jumped to menu item below. Plus it's not a part of `<a>` anymore so I cannot click if my mouse on top of the circle bullets.

So how to fix this problem without adding js code or changing the HTML structure?

**Note 1:** That navigation menu is the `sidebar-nav` here since I abstracted to make it easy to read: http://flatstrap.org/examples/fluid.html

**Note 2:** One *ugly* alternative I was thinking is to make the bullets as the background image. But that means I have to create tons of images since there are variations of color and I have to do it for white and gray background (:hover). I rather not do this.

**Note 3:** I need the big round bullet like in original code (it's UI design).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to make big font to have that around bullets as the status indicator, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle isn't part of the link because you set the :before pseudo element on the `li`. Set it the the actual `a` and it'll be part of the link.

As for the issue with jumping background colors; this happens because of your absurd `font-size` and non-matching `line-height`. Either find a larger circle symbol or create a circle with CSS.

[Here's a fork of your JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZnLw/) with a CSS circle instead.

Comment: Beautiful solution. I like the alternative of not using `content`

Answer (score 2):

**[See The Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yY84q/5/)**

Just Replace `li:before` with `li a:before` so you can have the link over your bullet to. And also for CSS HEX VALUE use this `'\2022'`

```
li{list-style-type:none;}
li a:before{content:'\2022'; font-size:40px;line-height:0;vertical-align:middle;}

li:hover {
    background:gray;
}

li a {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using explicit `line-height` for a `font-size` so big, if you remove that, it will work. But that's not the solution, so solution is to add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for your `:before` pseudo.

```
li:before{
   content:'\00b7'; 
   font-size:100px; 
   line-height:24px; 
   vertical-align:middle;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yY84q/2/)

I've added a link to the property, so that you can refer about the browser support.

Comment: This is creative. But still didn't solve the clickable problem. See here http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/yY84q/6/

Comment: @HP. Obviously it won't click, because when you use `:before` or `:after` pseudo, it will actually create a virtual element which has no relation with the current element what so ever, so if you want the bullets to be clickable, you need to declare `a:before` http://jsfiddle.net/yY84q/7/ and **not** `li:before`